# Calendar icon bootstrap and angularjs

Tags: angularjs, calendar

I want to have a calendar icon on my date picker but it seems to be not working. Only an arrow was shown but not the calendar icon

```
<span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
```

Comment: i wonder why the icon is not showing tho

Comment: Do you have glyphicon CSS file loaded? What's the Bootstrap version?

Comment: yes i do have glyphicon CSS loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want, but i don't know what's your angularJs question !!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this still does not load any calendar icon on my site

Comment: remove all bootstrap source in your page, and then put this sample sources, do you have icon fonts file in your project?